# Opentext content server unable to create/connect to database

Tags: sql-server, opentext

I am installing fresh copy of **opentext 16.2.8**, and when I try to create new database it keep on failing with the following error. I have installation of SQL Server 2016 standard

> Error: Could not connect. ----> Error stack ----> 1) E675217410:ODBC reported error.:[Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][DBNETLIB]Invalid connection. ----> 2) E675217410:ODBC reported error.:[Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][DBNETLIB]Invalid connection. [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][DBNETLIB]ConnectionOpen (ParseConnectParams()). ----> 3) E675086340:Could not connect.

Log

```
01/28/2021 17:42:18 INFO  [66024053273]  0000000168: ****** CAPIAllocConnect called ...
01/28/2021 17:42:18 INFO  [66024053380]  0000000169: KConnect::Connect(...) .. open the connection.
01/28/2021 17:42:18 INFO  [66024053671]  0000000170: KSqlODBC::SubclassConnect BCPEnabled() = TRUE
01/28/2021 17:42:36 INFO  [66042485428]  0000000171: KSqlODBC::SubclassConnect() DSN (connection string): DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=DESKTOP-8G0H7M6;UID=sa;DATABASE=master;
01/28/2021 17:42:36 ERROR [66042485572]  0000000172: ODBC diagnostic error: 1 ODBC error code: 0 ODBC state: HYT00 ODBC error: [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver]Login timeout expired
01/28/2021 17:42:36 ERROR [66042485650]  0000000173: KSql::Connect('DESKTOP-8G0H7M6','master','sa','*','','API100') --> 'Could not connect.',[sec: 18 msec: 431]
01/28/2021 17:42:36 INFO  [66042485692]  0000000174: KSql::Connect .. ConnectionType = ODBC
01/28/2021 17:42:36 INFO  [66042485720]  0000000175: KSql::Connect .. DatabaseType =   DB_UNKNOWN
01/28/2021 17:42:36 INFO  [66042485760]  0000000176: KSql::Connect .. MaxLength =      32767
01/28/2021 17:42:36 INFO  [66042485784]  0000000177: KSql::Connect .. MaxLongLength =  32767
01/28/2021 17:42:36 INFO  [66042485820]  0000000178: KSql::Connect .. SubQueryBlobs =  TRUE
01/28/2021 17:42:36 ERROR [66042485856]  0000000179: KConnect::Connect(...) --> 'Could not connect.'
```

Comment: Have you installed [the latest ODBC drivers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/download-odbc-driver-for-sql-server)? Seems like there should be `Driver={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};` in your connection string.

Comment: Thank you. Installing the latest ODBC drivers solved the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Installing the [latest ODBC drivers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/download-odbc-driver-for-sql-server) solved the issue. As mentioned in the comment by AlwaysLearning

Comment: For future readers of this. I downloaded the latest ODBC drivers, and had to update the opentext.ini file per this KB article https://knowledge.opentext.com/knowledge/cs.dll/kcs/kbarticle/view/KB9619634